# Is there a place where I can ask "how do I ..." for formatting questions

Tags: support, questions, formatting

I am often asking myself "how do I do ..." with formatting, but what I am trying to do is (afaict) not in the formatting help.

Where do I go with questions that are formatting related and not stats related?

How did you find that destination?  Is there a link that I missed?

Comment: Here? $\quad\quad$

Comment: @amoeba - how would I know that? That is cool, and I will start asking my question here.  How many formatting related questions are asked here?  It isn't something that I have seen, seen a link for, or seen a tag for.

Comment: E.g. http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math-display or http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formatting

Comment: I am surprised that there are only ~30-ish questions ever on those topics.  Thanks amoeba.  That answers the question.  I will ask here in meta, but without being an advanced user (I'm not) or without being an asker of strange questions (I'm that), I would never have known where to go.

Comment: For additional help with MathJax (besides just reading help on LaTeX I guess), math's meta offers [this tutorial & quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference#)

Comment: Hello EngrStudent. Do you maybe want to mark one of the answers as accepted (in order for this thread to appear "resolved" as I think it is)?

Comment: @amoeba - I don't like the answers.   Essentially nobody asks that stuff here. I was afraid to ask that here, but I did it anyway.  I don't believe there is any answer because I really think it is considered a non-issue by "the powers that be".  The next time I run into a "how do I " which I do when I'm answering or asking a few questions per day, I will test and see if it works.  If it does work then I can mark this as closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the question is about formatting posts/content on Cross Validated Stack Exchange, then as responded by amoeba in comments, ask here on Meta. Some related tags on this subject are [formatting](/questions/tagged/formatting), [math-display](/questions/tagged/math-display) and [design](/questions/tagged/design).

Also, take a look at the [markdown help](https://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 7):

Whether asking or answering a question, you will be typing into a textbox with a menu bar at its head.  At the very right of that menu bar is a "?" icon which when clicked produces this interface:

[image: Figure 1]

Use the icons, the menus, or the "advanced help" to get more information.

When *asking* a question, you will see more information in a panel appearing to the right:

[image: Figure 2]

One trick I use, especially for formatting comments, is to *start asking a question* (follow the "Ask Question" link at the upper right of any page) so I can avail myself of these features as well as the WYSIWIG rendering of the text.  I then copy the text and *abandon the page without posting the question* (this is important!).